# How do I open the locked house in Balime?

Tags: jagged-alliance-bia

There is a locked house in Balime with a "Quest Giver" inside that appears to need a key, where is that key located?  Or how does one get into that house?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need either a very high lock pick (99) or very high strength (99) to force open that door.  With 99 lock pick it still took a couple of attempts.  I never found a key that enabled easy opening of the door.

Quest inside is the Dahanko flakes limited edition box of cereal quest.